# Tunnel all network traffic through another Linux server

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, tunneling

I have two VMs both running Ubuntu 14.04, one is connected to the internet and accessible publicly but the second one is not. Now whenever I want to install something or run apt-get update, it does not work on the second one (obviously no internet connection). I want to setup something like a proxy which tells the second VM to send all its internet traffic through the first VM which has internet access. Is it possible? 
I tried doing ssh tunneling but I did not understand one bit of it to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working a few months back and if my memory serves, here is a good guide to help you out.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Internet_sharing